# Continuation of learning CAD/CAM/CAE packages

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Don't know about you but here in Spain, in the practice lessons we use some software related to the field (for example, ADAMs for Multibody Systems in MechE, right now). Then when the course ends, we don't mention / use the software until you start working in a company and you might don't remember anything at all or you just don't know enough.

I'd like to know what can I do in order **not to miss this knowledge and really master all this software** we are supposed to know. Do we really need to master all the software or a few are enough?

Practical example: I used MATLAB in few practices, but if I had to use MATLAB in a company I don't know how I should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few aspects to this.

Firstly it probably isn't practical to get hold of all of the software you might encounter in a future job because it is likely to be expensive and you have no way of knowing what version your future employer might be using. Many companies also use specialist or proprietary software that you may not even know about. It is also not entirely unknown for universities to use obscure or generally awful software for their own internal reasons. I was taught CAD on a dismal platform which was totally unsuited to general engineering because my university was sponsored by the company which made it.

The second issue is finding a way to practice which will actually be useful. Mechanical Engineering courses tend to be fairly broad  so it makes a certain amount of sense to pick an area that you are particularly interested in and make a project out of it. Similarly any practice you do will have much more value getting you a job if it is easy for you to demonstrate evidence of it. For example saying that you built a robot over the summer as a fun project to improve your skills will carry a lot more weight in an interview than saying that you spent 2 hours a day memorising Autocad keyboard shortcuts.

For example something like designing and building a working model aircraft would be good as you have something tangible to show for your efforts and it will demonstrate and ability to tackle real world problems rather than just abstract exercises.

The other thing is that an employer probably won't expect a recent engineering graduate to be a technical expert the moment they walk in. They will be more interested in your ability to learn and adapt and have a sound understanding of basic principles rather than lot of memorised information.

Probably the most useful area to focus on is CAD as this is pretty widely applicable to any field.

Comment: The other thing to do is to keep notes on how the software works & how you used it to solve specific problems. If you end up using the same software in the future you can refer to the notes to revive dormant brain cells.